# SQL combine two rows into one value

Tags: sql, sap-ase

I need to combine the values of two columns and place the value into the 3rd column. For example,
I have a table like so:

```
Name          Age         Key

Joe           4        
Mike          10           
Larry         20
```

I want an output where the key is a combination of both name and age columns.

```
Name          Age         Key

Joe           4           Joe/4     
Mike          10          Mike/10
Larry         20          Larry/20
```

I need to only combine into the Key field if Name is not an empty value. Combine with a / in between.

I have tried GROUP_CONCAT with no success, I have also tried concat with no success...

```
select Name, Age, (CASE WHEN table.Name IS NULL OR table.Name = '' then else concat(table.Name, '/', table.Age)) as Key from table
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using sybase on Aqua Data Studio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your query

```
SELECT Name,
       Age,
       ( CASE
           WHEN TABLE.Name IS NULL
                 OR TABLE.Name = '' THEN '' -- Missing then result 
           ELSE Concat(TABLE.Name, '/', TABLE.Age)
         END ) AS KEY --END missing
FROM   TABLE
```

Comment: For some reason I am getting an error that says the column prefix does not match with a table name or alias...

Comment: @JosephLasso - removed square bracket. check now

Comment: This seems perfect but I cant use the concat command. Wondering if it is becuase it is sybase

Comment: So i looked at it further.. to do this without using the concat command,  ELSE (TABLE.NAME +  '/' + TABLE.Age). thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simpler to use coalesce to deal with nulls

```
coalesce(Name + '/' + Age,'')
```

Comment: this looks like the simplest answer, but i can't use concat in sybase

Comment: Fixed, changed to `+`

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Name, Age, case when Name is not null then Name + "/" + Age end as Key from ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce would work here as well...

```
select Name
     , Age
     , concat(coalesce(table.Name,''), '/', coalesce(table.Age,''))) as Key 
from table
```

though calling it a key when age and name could be '' seems risky